# Display several items of a list into search bar

Tags: javascript, search

I have several lists.
ListA:
  item1,
  item2,
  …
ListB:
  item1,
  item2,

On click on an item, it appears as a value into a search bar.
I need to **add several items of differents lists** as values into the search bar. As it is now, on a click on an item, it only replace the current value into the search bar.

So I can have for example in the search bar: item A1 itemB2 …

Here is the code:

```
var items = document.getElementById("index");
var item = items.getElementsByTagName("h3");
for(var i=0; i<item.length; i++) {
  item[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    document.getElementById("search").value = (this.textContent || this.innerText);
    recherche();
  });
}
```

If anyone could help me on this, it would be much appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: can you make the demo of this ?

Comment: Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/umraaf9v/
On click on a list item I try to add value one after an another like this:
item A1 item A2 Item B1 etc… 
into the search field instead of having values replacing each other in the field. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want something like this.

```js
var item = document.querySelectorAll("#index h3");
itemArr = [];
for(var i=0; i<item.length; i++) {
  item[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
     var itemVal =  (this.textContent || this.innerText);
     var index = itemArr.indexOf(itemVal);
     if(index == -1){
     itemArr.push(itemVal);
     }else if (index > -1) {
        itemArr.splice(index, 1);
     }
     document.querySelector("#search").value = itemArr.join(",");
  });
}

function clearAll(){
  itemArr = [];
  document.querySelector("#search").value = "";
}
```

```css
h3{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.delete{
  cursor:pointer;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search"> <span class="delete" onclick="clearAll()">X</span>
<div id ="index">
<h3>item A1</h3>
<h3>item A2</h3>
<h3>item B1</h3>
<h3>item B2</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: One more question Rishi: Do you know if it's possible to delete text into the field and to click then on an other element? If I do so, the deleted element appears agin into the field, like it is kept in memory.

Comment: Can you make other question with example it is hard to understand

Comment: Actually I try to have a button which can delete the values of the var index. So it delete or flush the values displayed into the search bar, so you can start a new search without the old values

Comment: Thanks a lot Rishi ! The querySelector made the difference with what I was trying on my own.

Comment: @Hans : ok you can send me $15 by clicking on right tick mark, So that people know its solved question.